# MSBuild vs Visual Studio 2019 - won't pick up Additional Include Directories

Tags: c++, msbuild

Our VS 2019 project builds great. We have some extra include directories specified in the project's setting's C++/General/Additional Include Directories. When we go to a developer prompt and build the same project w/ msbuild, all the normal VS SDK includes get included, but the ones specified in the "Additional Include Directories" don't get picked up and used. We are wondering why not. maybe it's just because nobody on our team knows how to call msbuild! Could it be that simple?

msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=2019 ourProject.vcxproj

thanks in advance. I'm sure this is a smple one.